# Php openssl_pkey_export doesn't work

Tags: php, windows, blockchain, php-openssl

I'm trying to build a blockchain and for that, I need to generate a public and a private key and use the sign function and the verify function, from research I found that those functions were in the OpenSSL function, but I can't figure how this one works , I got the following code that I copied from the PHP doc :

```
// Create the keypair
$res=openssl_pkey_new();

// Get private key
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privkey);
// Get public key
$pubkey=openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$pubkey=$pubkey["key"];

$data = 'plaintext data goes here';

openssl_sign("hello",$signature,$privKey);
$test=openssl_verify("hello",$signature,$pubKey,"sha256");
echo $test;
```

and this gives me: openssl_pkey_export(): cannot get key from parameter 1.
ps: i'm on windows

Comment: The code wont actually work, there is [working examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php) on the manual. but the issue with the error is because you need to install the openssl module.

Comment: i installed OpenSSL module and it works on cmd but it still doesn't work with PHP  , ps: i used the working example,

Comment: Use [openssl_error_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php), for example https://3v4l.org/8p6VD then use the `error:02001002` msgs to find the reason. your code wont work for a couple of reason `$privkey != $privKey & $pubkey != $pubKey`